# Running unit tests after every build in VS.Net 2013 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ide, nunit, vs-unit-testing-framework

Is there any way of running tests automatically after each build?
I know this is possible in 2013 Premium/Ultimate ([link](http://goo.gl/PwA2zO)) but sure there are ways
to do this in the Community edition?

I'm using Nunit + adapter so it would be nice to have tests run through
the **adapter** instead of using post-build command-line events..?
*(which I can figure out myself tbh)*

IF I need to write a vsix, no problem, I'm capable of that too. Just need
a pointer in the right direction? If I should need to write one, I would
monitor files changed before build and only run the needed tests.

Comment: Found some references in case I would need to write an extension:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465178